# Netty Websockets

Tags: java, apache, websocket, netty

We have a Netty Websocket based server for HTTP communication. On the client side we can not implement netty and have to rely on plain http client (using apache http client). 
Is is possible to have a frame based message communication from pure http client to Websocket based server ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like Apache HTTP client supports websockets yet. https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/httpclient-973

Perhaps you could use https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client ?

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas. Can't we implement any other simple(Pure) HTTP client to communicate to Netty Websockets. We are in a peculiar situation where we can not change much in the client code. This client is running using TCP and on Server also we are using Netty TCP framework. But, the customer is asking for HTTPS communication from client to server and vice-versa due to client firewall issues.                              Could you please suggest something here ?                                             Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sid you can use the same ssl handlers you use for https when using websockets in netty, most firewalls only filter HTTP(port 80) and not HTTPS (port 443) so using ssl could help you bypass that firewall. However if the client side doesn't support websockets you pretty much stuck to downgrading your server to use normal requests